# How to circumvent float:left; behavior in a masonry layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, push

Here is a page I am working on:
https://1stamender.com/testing-elements.php

This is basically a list of latest articles on my site and right now I have a UI I'm looking to improve. Right now I have it defined using bootstrap and my own CSS and can't seem to find a solution.
Basically I can see there is some funky spacing due to the inherent way that divs handle float: left;.

It pushes divs into a new row versus try to push itself up to the div above it leaving for some awkward spacing. This can be fixed by setting a height but the heights will generally be different for each article.

I haven't the faintest idea how to do this CSS wise I've been googling forever...

Edit: Apologies I know you want to see the code itself:

```
echo '  
                <div class="articlecontainer">
                    <div class="articlepicture2">
                        <a href="article.php?articlenumber='.$articlenumber.'"><img src="'.$mainpic.'" alt="'.$headline.'" width="100%"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="articledescription2">
                        <a href="article.php?articlenumber='.$articlenumber.'" class="articlelink2"><strong><span class="headlinearticle2">'.$headline.'</span></strong><br>
                        '.substr($content,0,100).'...</a>
                        <hr>
                        Written by: ';
                        $sqlauthor = "SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT WHERE USERNAME='$articleauthor'";
                        $resultauthor = $conn->query($sqlauthor);
                        if ($resultauthor->num_rows > 0) {
                                // output data of each row
                                $rowauthor = $resultauthor->fetch_assoc();
                                $authordisplayname = $rowauthor['DISPLAYNAME'];
                                echo '<i>'.$authordisplayname.'</i><br>';
                                echo 'Overall Rating: ';
                                echo '<img src="images/main/rating/'.$star.'.png" alt="Rating 0.5" width="80">';
                        }

                        echo '
                    </div>
                </div>

            ';
```

CSS:

```
.articlecontainer{
background-color: #666;
border: solid 1px #000;
color: #fff;
padding: 0px !important;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-right: 20px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-bottom:10px !important;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 25%;
float: left;
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just use flex - joking! What have you already tried? Looks like this could be caused by a *step-down* effect you tend to get with floating elements in specific ways.

Comment: You could have variables for three columns and add always every 1-st item to the 1-st, every 2-nd to the 2-nd and every 3-rd to the 3-rd column variable and then print out these variables.

Comment: I figured this was something I could do, but unfortunately it means I would need to create a php modulus to tell whether its a left, center, and right, and it just seems very bulky to me. Is there really no CSS to resolve such a simple issue?

Comment: you could use css-columns, but then you would change the post's order (not left->right, but up->down)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Flexbox to float elements like magazine/newspaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296062/css-flexbox-to-float-elements-like-magazine-newspaper)

Comment: This is called a masonry layout, that will help your googling.

Comment: This is the solution! I've never even heard of that term till today thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use three variables for each column and always toggle the used one or you could use css-columns, but you would change the posts-order to top to bottom.

CSS-Columns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns
PHP: Something like this:

```
$column = 1;
$column_1_html = "";
$column_2_html = "";
$column_3_html = "";
foreach($boxes => $box) {
    $box_html = "...";
    if($column == 1) {
        $column = 2;
        $column_1_html .= $box_html;
    } else if($column == 2) {
        $column = 3;
        $column_2_html .= $box_html;
    } else if($column == 3) {
        $column = 1;
        $column_3_html .= $box_html;
    }
}
```

As stated in the comments this library might be something for you: https://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Comment: I was thinking initially of a solution like this. It just seemed a tad wasteful to be wasting resources that I think some simple client-side CSS can do. Though maybe CSS doesn't have the ability to do this without having to implement this... Good code and simple solution though!